# Deleting previous mapboxgl.Popup() existing on mapbox map

Tags: javascript, popup, delete, mapbox-gl

Before adding new `mapboxgl.Popup()`, I have to delete the existing ones if there are any. My code is:

```js
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(middleCoordinates)
        .setHTML(`Distance: ${measure}`)
        .addTo(map);
```

But in this way, new ones are added. How can I delete existing popup if there are any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally opted for another slightly better approach:

```
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(middleCoordinates)
        .setHTML(`Distance: ${measure}`);

const popups = document.getElementsByClassName("mapboxgl-popup");

    if (popups.length) {

        popups[0].remove();

    }

popup.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

After some testing I found a solution. First I declare a variable that contains the popup and if isn't open, then it's added to the map. Otherwise it's removed.

```
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(middleCoordinates)
        .setHTML(`Distance: ${measure}`);

if (popup.isOpen()) {

    popup.remove();

} else {

    popup.addTo(this.refMapboxMap.current.map.map);

}
```